# ERD and normalization 3FD

Tags: normalization, database-normalization, erd

is this relationship is true in 3FD normalization? and what can i do with the (phone number), it is Determines all rows? please any one help me to convert this relationship to 3FD and in Correct relationship.

[image: enter image description]

Comment: Just a note: the primary key of patients = PID, Doctors=DID, consultation= CID

Comment: Normalization is based on functional dependencies & join dependencies. What are yours? What reference are you using for "normalization"?

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, comments are ephemeral. Please use *text* whereever possible, and not images as a replacement.

Comment: "what can i do with the (phone number), it is Determines all rows?" is unintelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone number will not be a good determinant for `PATIENTS` if this is a real world example.  Some patients will share phone numbers, some patients will have multiple phone numbers, and some patients (young children, homeless people) might not have a phone number at all.

**Your model is nominally in 3NF already**.  Every non-key attribute of each of the tables is fully functionally dependent on every candidate key (and nothing else).  This is trivial in your case because you've declared surrogate keys for your primary key and you haven't declared unique constraints for any alternative candidate keys.

Comment: "Every non-key attribute of each of the tables is fully functionally dependent on the all primary keys." only justifies 2NF. And you mean "candidate keys".

Comment: what do you mean of (This is trivial in your case because you've declared surrogate keys for your primary key and you haven't declared unique constraints for any alternative candidate keys.) please, What do I need these keys?

Comment: @OsamaAL-Atraqchi - You don't *need* these additional keys, but you might *have* them, depending on what your data looks like.  When you create a surrogate key (e.g. a meaningless unique number) for a primary key, then each row will be determined by that key, by definition.  What isn't clear in your model is if there are any other columns besides the "*ID" columns that would also be unique determinants of your tables.  If there are no other _candidate keys_ (and no transitive functional dependencies) then you are going to be in 3NF.

Comment: Thank you Very Much Brother, The idea became clear, thank you brother ...